# Coarea-like formula for BV function (not its derivative)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, reference-request, soft-question

Let $f \in BV(\Omega)$. The coarea formula states that

$$Df = \int_{\mathbb R} D \chi_{\{f >h\}} \,  dh.$$

Do we also have that
$$f = \int_{\mathbb R}  \chi_{\{f >h\}} \,  dh$$
holds?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on whether or not $$0 = \int_{-\infty}^0 1 \, dh.$$

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean let $f$ be the function that is identically zero and see what the formula states.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Thanks. Then does a similar formula to the one in the question hold?

Comment: I doubt it.$\mbox{}$